# Scaling in MathJax with respect to text direction

Tags: right-to-left, mathjax

I'm working on a site which is in Arabic (default text direction is "right to left") and I'm using "Noto Naskh Arabic" font for arabic text and Latin-Modern for latin text which I'm definig by the following css code:

```
*[dir="ltr"] {
        font-size: 20px !important;
        font-family:"Latin-Modern";
}
```

Users may need to enter mathematical equations and I'm using 'Mathjax' for this purpose, the problem is that:

1. Fractions are displayed without the horizontal line
2. Equations are displayed with different sizes between arabic and latin paragraph as when I write

   some text in english here $\int f(x)dx $

I have come to a slution to the first problem using css

```
span:lang(ar).MathJax { 
    direction: ltr !important;  
    font-family:"Latin-Modern";
    }
```

For the second problem, I need to know if there is a way to automatically specify scale separately for equation which are embedded in Arabic paragraph end those embedded in English paragraph.

Comment: Not an answer but are you aware that there's https://github.com/Edraak/arabic-mathjax?

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep writing equations with English symbols.

Comment: You might want to paste a live example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Here is a [live example](http://math.sinwajim.com/testing-mathjax/)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the main issue is that you have to scale in the first place. I'm guessing you did that because MathJax is rendering too large in RTL contexts.

It looks like MathJax is having issues detecting the correct ex-height of the surrounding font. That can be caused by various problems, from fonts not having a correct ex-height to bad CSS interactions; from a quick test it's not the fonts.

As a workaround you can disable font matching in the MathJax configuration

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
     "HTML-CSS": {matchFontHeight: false},
     SVG: {matchFontHeight: false},
     CommonHTML: {matchFontHeight: false}
});
```

You should then also disable the scaling you applied.

Comment: I'm sorry, this solve partially the problem (as you can see in the example). Still, need to find a way to scale equations which are inserted between Arabic text. I think of a way to add `dir="ltr"` in mathjax span elements besides MathJax_Display class.

Comment: The ltr content uses a bigger font-size (21px vs 16px). If you change your CSS to the same value, the MathJax output will be sized appropriately.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, as in 16px Latin text size will be too small in comparison to Arabic text, maybe I can try to find another font to use that have the same height as the "Noto Naskh" font I'm using, but this will not solve the problem globally.

Comment: You can always specify a font size for the mathjax output within rtl (or ltr). That doesn't need MathJax scaling, just plain CSS.