# Width Issue with MathJax 2.7.5 when text direction is set to "right-to-left"

Tags: css, right-to-left, mathjax

My site is set to use right to left language. After upgrading to MathJax 2.7.5, I noticed that the mathematical notations that are in a text having "right-to-left" direction are displayed with extra blank space to the right. All previous version from v2.7.1 to 2.7.4 did not have this problem.
Here is my configuration code for MatJax

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {
            inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"] ],
            displayMath: [["$$","$$"], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
            processEscapes: true,
            preview: "none",
            },
        "HTML-CSS": {
            matchFontHeight: false,
            availableFonts: ["TeX"],
            webFont: 'Latin-Modern',
            preferredFont: 'Latin-Modern',
            },
        CommonHTML: {
            matchFontHeight: false
            },
        SVG: {
            matchFontHeight: false
            },
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

and here is the CSS lines that I used for a [good mathematical notation appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870980/scaling-in-mathjax-with-respect-to-text-direction)

```
span:lang(ar).MathJax{ 
    direction: ltr !important;  
    font-family:"Latin-Modern";
    font-size: 22px !important;
    }
span:lang(ar).mjx-chtml{ 
    direction: ltr !important;  
    font-family:"Latin-Modern";
    font-size: 22px !important;
    }
span:lang(ar).MJXp-math{ 
    direction: ltr !important;  
    font-family:"Latin-Modern";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px !important;
    }
```

What's changing with MathJax 2.7.5